# HTML page won't load reference scripts

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a very basic HTML page that has a little bit of Javascript functionalities. Nothing fancy, just some DOM manipulation. Everything was working fine and then all the scripts magically stopped working. Upon looking into firebug, it seems as though this script is working fine:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

These two references, however, don't seem to load up at all anymore:

```
  <script src="/Bootsrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

custom.js is in the root directory and the other is in a Bootstrap folder. Everything was fine yesterday until it wasn't and I can't get it to work again.

```js
function betterWork(this) {
  if(confirm("Is this your final selection?"))
  {
//  document.location = '#';
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  }
}

function youCantDoThat() {
  alert("That isn't a Pokemon ya doof.");
}

function tooDamnBad() {
  var changeText = document.getElementById("textToChange");
  var newText = document.getElementById("newText");
  changeText.innerHTML = "Too Damn Bad!";
  newText.innerHTML = "Pick One Anyways :)";
}
```

```css
.imageSize {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>JS Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="text-center" id="textToChange">Pick A Starter Pokemon</h1>
    <h3 id="newText" class="text-center"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="img" onclick="betterWork()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://assets19.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//001.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="img" onclick="betterWork()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/13/007Squirtle_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Explorers_of_Sky.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105230449" />
    </div>
    <div id="img" onclick="betterWork()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/0/6087/2438704-1202149925_t.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="img3" onmouseover="youCantDoThat()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/c38fff03b8dd7aaf75037eb18619da57/tumblr_n436i3Falo1sndv3bo1_1280.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="img4" onclick="betterWork()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/010.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="img5" onclick="betterWork()" class="imageSize col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/camphalfbloodroleplay/images/7/77/Pikachu.png/revision/latest?cb=20141004224742" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="tooDamnBad()">I Don't Like These Pokemon</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer></footer>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Bootsrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you SURE the paths are correct for the page you are looking at? e.g. if `custom.js` is at root, change it to `/custom.js` then it will be at root which ever page level you're at

Comment: I am absolutely sure the path is correct. I did try adding the slash to the beginning before posting this and that didn't change anything. This has been broken since yesterday evening and I've tried a lot of things. I even realized my footer was all screwed up and fixed that but nothing would get it to work. After I posted this, though, I looked through the document again and checked the scripts - looks like they are there, just not working. I refreshed and now it works again. I have no idea why or what caused the scripts to just decide to not work but now they do. Computers = magic.

Comment: Open your browsers F12 tools and look at the network tab to see why the requests to the JavaScript files are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing why a script is not loading should begin with opening your console, looking at the resources tab, and determining whether and *why* the browser had an error loading the script.

Alternatively you can open the script from your browser directly and your webpage will notify you. For example, if your script is located at the path `/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js` and your host name is `localhost`, navigate to `localhost/Bootstrap/boostrap.js`.

Interpreting the results:

- if the result is a `403` error it means that your webserver is not able to open this file. You will need to grant `read` access to your webserver.
- if the result is a `404` error it means that the file is actually not at the path you specified. You will need to debug step by step and figure out why. An additional stack overflow question may resolve this if needed.
- if the result is a different error, the meaning of it can be googled and you can comment and ask for additional clarification